# syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, rvm

I tried to create a new project and ran "$ rails new testx" but go the below syntax error... what has gone wrong??? 
As seen below I have Ruby V1.9.3 and rails V1.2.0 installed in the RVM.

```
macjam$ rails new tests

/Users/macjam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3- p550/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': /Users/macjam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activesupport-1.4.0/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:267: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
    when 1: "#{number}st"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 1.2 is **quite old** and doesn't work with ruby 1.9.  If you look at `/Users/macjam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/activesupport-1.4.0/lib/active_support/inflector.rb` line 267 where the error originates you'll see a `case` expression. Use of colons in `case` is no longer supported in ruby 1.9.  Downgrade ruby or upgrade to rails 4.

Comment: thank you for the answer! I changed the rails version from 1.2.0 =>2.3.18 and it started to work!! Thank you Dean!!

Comment: Actually, colon instead of `then` in `case` and `if` expressions was *never* allowed. It was added to the interpreter as an experiment, but never officially documented or specified, and matz has always made it clear that the syntax is *not* supported and *must not* be used.